# Unpivot yahoo finance multiple ticker download

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, yahoo-finance, pandas-melt

I am trying to unpivot a yahoo finance download.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

data = yf.download("AAPL WMT", start="2023-05-01", end=today).round(2)
```

Running this script I get:

| Date | Adj Close | Adj Close | Close | Close | High | High | Low | Low | Open | Open | Volume | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | AAPL | WMT | AAPL | WMT | AAPL | WMT | AAPL | WMT | AAPL | WMT | AAPL | WMT |
| 2023-05-01 | 169.36 | 151.02 | 169.59 | 151.59 | 170.45 | 152.54 | 168.64 | 150.93 | 169.28 | 151.04 | 52472900 | 3803200 |
| 2023-05-02 | 168.31 | 150.61 | 168.54 | 151.18 | 170.35 | 151.49 | 167.54 | 149.46 | 170.09 | 151.47 | 48425700 | 3776500 |
| 2023-05-03 | 167.22 | 150.05 | 167.45 | 150.62 | 170.92 | 152.1 | 167.16 | 150.27 | 169.5 | 151.56 | 65136000 | 4111500 |
| 2023-05-04 | 165.56 | 150.47 | 165.79 | 150.47 | 167.04 | 150.99 | 164.31 | 149.49 | 164.89 | 150.55 | 81235400 | 4670400 |
| 2023-05-05 | 173.33 | 151.77 | 173.57 | 151.77 | 174.3 | 152.01 | 170.76 | 149.83 | 170.98 | 150.3 | 113316400 | 4850000 |
| 2023-05-08 | 173.26 | 152.72 | 173.5 | 152.72 | 173.85 | 152.95 | 172.11 | 151.06 | 172.48 | 151.27 | 55962800 | 4975400 |
| 2023-05-09 | 171.53 | 152.98 | 171.77 | 152.98 | 173.54 | 153.18 | 171.6 | 152.34 | 173.05 | 152.72 | 45326900 | 5069900 |
| 2023-05-10 | 173.32 | 152.55 | 173.56 | 152.55 | 174.03 | 154.35 | 171.9 | 151.23 | 173.02 | 153.69 | 53724500 | 5275900 |
| 2023-05-11 | 173.51 | 153.12 | 173.75 | 153.12 | 174.59 | 153.27 | 172.17 | 152.0 | 173.85 | 152.55 | 49514700 | 3975600 |
| 2023-05-12 | 172.57 | 153.07 | 172.57 | 153.07 | 174.06 | 154.07 | 171.0 | 152.71 | 173.62 | 153.6 | 45497800 | 5371800 |

I am trying to pivot it to this, where the Ticker is now a column:

| Date | Ticker | Close | High | Low | Open | Volume | Adj Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2023 | AAPL | 169.59 | 170.45 | 168.64 | 169.28 | 52472900 | 169.36 |
| 5/2/2023 | AAPL | 168.54 | 170.35 | 167.54 | 170.09 | 48425700 | 168.31 |
| 5/3/2023 | AAPL | 167.45 | 170.92 | 167.16 | 169.5 | 65136000 | 167.22 |
| 5/4/2023 | AAPL | 165.79 | 167.04 | 164.31 | 164.89 | 81235400 | 165.56 |
| 5/5/2023 | AAPL | 173.57 | 174.3 | 170.76 | 170.98 | 1.13E+08 | 173.33 |
| 5/8/2023 | AAPL | 173.5 | 173.85 | 172.11 | 172.48 | 55962800 | 173.26 |
| 5/9/2023 | AAPL | 171.77 | 173.54 | 171.6 | 173.05 | 45326900 | 171.53 |
| 5/10/2023 | AAPL | 173.56 | 174.03 | 171.9 | 173.02 | 53724500 | 173.32 |
| 5/11/2023 | AAPL | 173.75 | 174.59 | 172.17 | 173.85 | 49514700 | 173.51 |
| 5/12/2023 | AAPL | 172.57 | 174.06 | 171 | 173.62 | 45497800 | 172.57 |
| 5/1/2023 | WMT | 151.59 | 152.54 | 150.93 | 151.04 | 3803200 | 151.02 |
| 5/2/2023 | WMT | 151.18 | 151.49 | 149.46 | 151.47 | 3776500 | 150.61 |
| 5/3/2023 | WMT | 150.62 | 152.1 | 150.27 | 151.56 | 4111500 | 150.05 |
| 5/4/2023 | WMT | 150.47 | 150.99 | 149.49 | 150.55 | 4670400 | 150.47 |
| 5/5/2023 | WMT | 151.77 | 152.01 | 149.83 | 150.3 | 4850000 | 151.77 |
| 5/8/2023 | WMT | 152.72 | 152.95 | 151.06 | 151.27 | 4975400 | 152.72 |
| 5/9/2023 | WMT | 152.98 | 153.18 | 152.34 | 152.72 | 5069900 | 152.98 |
| 5/10/2023 | WMT | 152.55 | 154.35 | 151.23 | 153.69 | 5275900 | 152.55 |
| 5/11/2023 | WMT | 153.12 | 153.27 | 152 | 152.55 | 3975600 | 153.12 |
| 5/12/2023 | WMT | 153.07 | 154.07 | 152.71 | 153.6 | 5371800 | 153.07 |

I cannot find any good examples of this here and I am pretty sure it is possible with melt but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
out = data.stack().reset_index(level=1, names=["", "Ticker"]).sort_values(by="Ticker")
```

Output :

```
print(out)

           Ticker  Adj Close  Close   High    Low   Open    Volume
Date                                                              
2023-05-01   AAPL     169.36 169.59 170.45 168.64 169.28  52472900
2023-05-02   AAPL     168.31 168.54 170.35 167.54 170.09  48425700
2023-05-11   AAPL     173.51 173.75 174.59 172.17 173.85  49514700
...           ...        ...    ...    ...    ...    ...       ...
2023-05-01    WMT     151.02 151.59 152.54 150.93 151.04   3803200
2023-05-08    WMT     152.72 152.72 152.95 151.06 151.27   4975400
2023-05-12    WMT     153.07 153.07 154.07 152.71 153.60   5371800

[20 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: I am getting "NameError: name '_' is not defined"

Comment: Oops sorry, answer updated! Can you try again ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Now I am getting "TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'"  Could this be because my installation needs to be updated?

Comment: What's your pandas version `print(pd.__version__)` ? I'm using `2.0.1`. The `names` parameter was introduced in [`1.5.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#other-enhancements).

Comment: 1.4.3, let me update.  It has been a while.